# How to get NGINX proxy_pass to multiple ReactJS apps created using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I am using `create-react-app` to build a bunch of react apps for various modules in my application, for ex: Users, Leads, Campaigns, etc.

I have containerized all the apps using Docker and NGINX.

I would like to have ***one*** nginx gateway which will redirect to my apps based on the path.

For example:

```
https://www.example.com/users --> users app
https://www.example.com/products --> products app
```

I tried setting this up based on various articles I came across on the internet, but with no success. I basically have two problems:

1. Referencing static files - Create React app usually injects a script tag such as `<script src="/static/....."></script>` in the `index.html` file, which prevents the HTML from loading the scripts (as it looks for them in the gateway's root directory). I was able to fix that by setting the build script to use a `PUBLIC_URL` variable set to `/users` or `/products` as required.
2. After I set `PUBLIC_URL` and built the container, now NGINX for some reason gives me a `301 Moved permanently` response and doesn't proxy properly.

I am not sure what I am missing. I'm sure this is a very common use case.

For each of my react apps, I have created a Dockerfile as follows

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And an `nginx.conf` as follows:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  client_max_body_size 100M;

}
```

Here is the `nginx.conf` for my gateway:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location /products/ {
      proxy_pass http://products/;
  }
  location /users/ {
      proxy_pass http://users/;
  }
  location /sales/ {
      proxy_pass http://sales/;
  }

}
```

And finally, my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"
networks:
  ylib:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    networks:
      - ylib
  products:
    image: products
    container_name: products
    ports:
      - 8881:80
    networks:
      - ylib
  sales:
    image: sales
    container_name: sales
    ports:
      - 8882:80
    networks:
      - ylib
  orders:
    image: orders
    container_name: orders
    ports:
      - 8883:80
    networks:
      - ylib
```

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: What request URI exactly gives you HTTP 301? What is `Location` HTTP response header value?

Comment: Assume my users app is hosted at http://localhost:8001/users. If I hit http://localhost:8001/users in the browser, I get a 301 Response with Location = http://localhost/users

Comment: Hey currently having a similar problem, any solution OP ?